# how to stop scroll issue in light-box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox

I have implemented the light box to pop up my images but I have little issue because after the user click the image it pops up and all however there seems to be a scroll bar is introduced.
How to stop this? This is in their original design as well .

When the image pops up, I want to stop the scroll.

Comment: Show us what you tried(code) jsfiddle would be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

possibly using css

```
.somewrapperclass{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

what plugin are you using? fancybox?